# JS Redirect if Cookie Exists

Tags: javascript

I'm using a simple .html page to redirect someone to page A if they don't have a cookie. If they do have the cookie I want to send them to page B.

The issue I'm having is someone will get redirected to page A, but when they push the back button on page A, the .js isn't executing on my simple .html page and sending them to page B. Instead, the blank .html page is loading and that's it.

```
//this function fixed Safari
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
    window.location.reload()
  }
};
window.onunload = function() {}; // this seems to have fixed Firefox
setTimeout(function() {
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("visitedinhour=") >= 0) {
        // They've been here before.
        window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
    } else {
        // set a new cookie
        document.cookie = "visitedinhour=true; max-age=" + 3600;
        window.location = 'https://www.bing.com';
    }
}, 200);
```

What I'd like to happen is someone visits my .html page, is redirected to page A, then click the back button, and are redirected to page B.

**UPDATE:** Firefox seems to work as intended. Chrome and Safari don't. Chrome goes back to the page before my .html page and Safari still loads the blank .html page.

**UPDATE 2:** Safari is fixed; Chrome isn't working as intended. When on Bing.com and you click the back button the browser goes to the page it was on before my .html page with this code.

Comment: Do you have an application layer or do you just serve static HTML / JS?

Comment: Just static HTML/JS from AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a known issue in Firefox.

Try to set an empty function to be called on window.onunload:

`window.onunload = function() { };`

This is because Firefox (and Safari, and Opera) keeps the website intact. it does not immediately destroy your page to go onto the next one, which results in a much faster and smoother back/forward page transitions for the user.

**Update**

This should work for Safari (it will force a reload when page is loaded from bfcache):

```js
window.onpageshow = function(event) {
  if (event.persisted) {
    window.location.reload()
  }
};
```

**Update 2:**

This code should be compatible with all browsers although you may need to use the above snippets too.

```js
window.addEventListener("pageshow", function (event) {
  var historyTraversal = 
        event.persisted || 
        (
          // Check if performance not undefined (restored from cache)
          typeof window.performance != "undefined" &&
          
          // Check if the back button was used
          window.performance.navigation.type === 2
        );
  
  if (historyTraversal) {
    // Handle page restore and reload the page
    window.location.reload();
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems to fix Firefox, but both Chrome and Safari don't work. Chrome goes to the page before my simple html page, and Safari loads the blank page.

Comment: that fixed Safari. Now the only issue left is with Chrome. It seems to skip over my .html page completely when clicking the back button from bing.com and instead goes to the page the browser was on before the .html page with this code.

Comment: thanks; I was just looking at a similar snippet. I think update 2 may be depreciated now: https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#obsolete

I'm not sure if it can be rewritten with this maybe: https://w3c.github.io/navigation-timing/#dom-performancenavigationtiming

Comment: I've realized that it doesn't really matter if Chrome skips to the page before, as the way I'm implementing this my .html page won't have a history before it, so it actually works if I open my html page in a new tab. Thanks for the help!